# How long can a typical god last on Earth without using power?

Tags: survival, gods

A god is being voluntarily banished to the mortal realm a.k.a the miserable world of the living, location of your choice. Supernatural powers are forbidden, meaning to say the statistics or luck as the earthling like to call it applies!

This god can neither manipulate anyone's luck including himself or herself, nor could s/he commits any of the seven sins. Prayer/profanity to him/herself or any colleges is strictly prohibited. Each day the god must clock up a mileage of 10 km and fill a quota of answering 99 queries on any topic/subjects of the other party's choice in person. Any violation will result in being prosecuted by Zeus in person and at a distance. Trust me an underground bunker with lightning rods don't help at all if you crossed the mighty one!

How long can a god last and at which site would be his/her paradise?

Comment: Being voluntarily banished is something a person or deity does to themselves. This suggest volition & choice. If Zeus is on punishment duty, is this deity an Olympian ancient Greek variety of deity? Greek deities didn't have paradises, so that last question may be edited out as unnecessary & spurious.

Comment: with "Supernatural powers are forbidden" do you also include immortality?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: "How long can a god last" What this *last* means? Die? Going crazy? If he's a god, he's not constrained by physical attributes. He can walk 24 hours forever and not feel tired. Bored, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Get a job at a call centre with a 6 km commute. Possibly at an IT helpdesk...or a bank for best results

Comment: Why? What makes this answer better than some other answer that someone might give? Please [edit] to elaborate on your reasoning.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: `Each day the god must clock up a mileage of 10 km and fill a quota of answering 99 queries on any topic/subjects of the other party's choice in person.` I would have thought the answer obvious.